# `no matching function for call to ‘islower(std::string&)’`

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check whether my input is uppercase and if not change to change it, but I get an error message: `no matching function for call to ‘islower(std::string&)’`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void enterNames(std::string* names, int lenght)
{
    for (int count{ 0 }; count != lenght; ++count) {
        std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, names[count]);
        if (std::islower(names[0][0])) {
            names[0] = std::toupper(names[0][0]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int lenght{ 10 };
    auto* names{ new std::string[lenght]{} };
    enterNames(names, lenght);
    delete[] names;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower) helps. You're feeding an entire string, the function expects a single character.

Comment: The confusion likely comes from you thinking you have a single string when you in fact have an array of strings.

Comment: 95% of the code in the question has nothing to do with the problem. Remove irrelevant code. Sometimes that will point you to the answer; if it doesn't, post the smallest code that shows the problem.

Comment: @sweenish I think I understand you but Do you have any idea how I can access to first string from my array and then access to first letters of this string for check if is uppercase ?

Comment: @MateuszKacperski `names[0]` is the 1st string, and `names[0][0]` is the 1st character of the 1st string.

Comment: @MateuszKacperski on a side note, when you need to `ignore()` characters in a stream, you should do so after the operation that left the characters behind in the first place, not before the next operation. So, in your example, the `ignore()` in `enterNames()` should be moved to `howMany()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys ! :)

my answer is:

```
void enterNames(std::string* names, int lenght)
{
    for(int count{ 0 }; count != lenght; ++count)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter name #" << (count+1) << ": ";
        std::getline( std::cin >> std::ws, names[count] );

        if(islower(names[count][0]))
        {
            names[count][0] = toupper(names[count][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything is algright :)

ps. @Remy Lebeau thank you for advanced i moved my ignore() to 'how_many'

Regards. Mateusz Kacperski.